# How does one find which tags they created?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, taxonomist-badge

Is there some way to tell who has created which tags, and when? If a method doesn't exist I would petition SO to add this, as I would very much enjoy seeing tags I created being used by other people.

SO must track creator meta-data on tags since a badge is awarded for creating a tag used by 50+ questions (taxidermist).

Comment: Taxidermist, lol. Would that be a badge awarded for the first killing and stuffing of a troll poster? :)

Comment: @random: Isn't this a separate feature request from showing which tag generated a taxonomist badge?  (Is there a way to view tags I've created which have not earned a taxonomist that I've missed?)

Comment: For finding out who created the tag, it's status-completed (though only when it cracks that 50 use barrier). But when a tag goes without a Taxonomist badge, it's another related issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46126/did-i-create-this-tag @gno

Comment: @random: That's what I'm saying: it seems to me this post goes with that issue (finding all tags you've created) and *not* with finding tags that generated taxonomist.  Of course the latter is a subset of the former.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing in your user page that will help with this, but following the chain below you might be able to figure out if you asked the first question with a specific tag. However, I'm not sure how retagging and/or deleted questions are treated in relation to the taxonomist badge.

`Tag -> sort by newest -> last page -> question on the bottom`, should be the earliest question asked with that tag, but still not guaranteed that that question or that user created the tag.

Comment: Note a tag can be created on a newer question and then included on an older question, so anyone trying this needs to check for that.  If the tag was created on an even older question and then removed (including if the question was deleted for any reason), you can't see that with this method.

Answer (score 3):

I have a list of which users created which tags, but Jeff has said he doesn't think any good can come from disclosing this information. I may be persuaded to help you if it's regarding a specific tag or user, but I won't help you if the tag has less than 50 occurrences.

In the general case nothing from SO will help you in finding such information, and you'll have to compile it on your own.

Comment: Naw, don't worry about it, I was just curious to how some of my created tags were being used, but then I could remember which tags I created.

Comment: couldn't rather,

Comment: Once you've got `taxonomist`, could there be a way to find out wich tag helped you get it? (Today I logged in and much to my surprise I got one! I guess this could be a question all in itself...)

Answer (score 2):

One does not....  Maybe the data dumps... But this is not visible at this time as far as I know...

Answer (score 0):

This is now covered by the **Taxonomist** badge.

To see a list of all those with the badge and what tag they created (so long as it is still in use), check out the [Taxonomist](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/badges/11/taxonomist) badge page.

To see what you alone created, check out the bottom portion of your user profile.

Comment: No, not in general, because the Taxonomist badge is only awarded once, and only for tags with at least 50 questions.

Comment: First one is free with the badge. Extra comes with tinkering in the data dump. Otherwise, it's stacks on for gaming the badge.