# Is there a way to find which tags you've created?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, badges, taxonomist-badge

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How does one find which tags they created?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10888/how-does-one-find-which-tags-they-created)
>   [Can I find out which tags I have created?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82/can-i-find-out-which-tags-i-have-created)

Once you've got taxonomist, could there be a way to find out wich tag helped you get it? Today I logged in and much to my surprise I got one! Only thing I did was changing some tags like <kbd>office2007</kbd> -> <kbd>office-2007</kbd> and some others (I don't recall every retag I've done, and the system doesn't allow to see a list of one's edits to others questions/answers).

I guess I had (slim) hopes to get one, but it really came as a surprise, as I imagined someone else would have made (for example)  <kbd>office-2007</kbd> before, and then got edited because of the  <kbd>office2007</kbd> majority, so in any case the one who would get the `taxonomist` badge would be the original poster.

Comment: If your question is, "What tag got me this badge?" you posted a dupe in your own question. If it's, "Why did I get this badge for doing x?", then edit it as so.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, see [Can I find out which tags I have created?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82/can-i-find-out-which-tags-i-have-created)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you can never find out what contributed to getting any particular badge.

This is [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge/101#101), although it's not the most popular design decision in the world.

Comment: It's just that it *feels* a bit weird to receive a badge and not knowing *why*.

Comment: Well the *why* is missing from every badge.

Comment: You are right, but most are either generic (Voted 300 times, Left 10 comments, etc), close on time (First edit, First flagged post) or easy to check (Question favorited by 25 users, Answer voted up 100 times). The *only* badge I can see in the list (may be missing one) that is impossible to check how you got it (unless you have a very good memory **and** are *certain that no one created that tag before*) is `Taxonomist`.

Comment: @voyager: If I get a Nice Answer badge, unless I happen to have been watching that answer it would take a *lot* of work to find out which one it is.