# Is it possible to un-associate a bounty given to another person

Tags: support, bounties

I have assigned a bounty for a question asked by another person, but would it be possible to revert back that action so that I can remove the bounty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have assigned a bounty to a question you can't remove it.  Hence the confirmation popup.

Answer (score 1):

Once you assign a bounty, that rep is gone forever.  Actually, that's not strictly true; a diamond mod can refund the bounty if you have a valid reason (or [if they feel like it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46126/did-i-create-this-tag)).  It's probably likely that you don't (and they won't), though.

Comment: It would have been more like, hey I made a mistake and gave a bounty can I revert it back within say a few minutes of that. Its possible that no one has viewed it so far.

Comment: @Joshua: you could always flag the question for moderator attention and try your luck.  It's a bit hard to "accidentally" add a bounty though, there is the warning and everything ;-)