# What about adding CreationDate to Tags in SEDE database?

Tags: feature-request, tags, data-explorer

Would it be possible (from the technical viewpoint) adding creation date to the Database Schema of SEDE.<sup>1</sup> (Or maybe even *id of the user* who created the tag or *id of the question* where it was created.)

I do not know much about databases and SQL, so I have no idea whether this would be technically possible. I would imagine that it is virtually impossible to fill this in for already existing entries, should the database scheme be changed. (I hope you will pardon my ignorance and someone more knowledgeable or someone from SE staff will be kind enough to explain the technical problems with this suggestion, if there are any.)

But if such change is possible, I think it would be useful. I have seen several questions asking how to find out when or by whom a particular tag was created. For example (ordered by id):

- [Can I find out which tags I have created?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82/can-i-find-out-which-tags-i-have-created)
- [Who created which tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22140/who-created-which-tag)
- [How does one find which tags they created?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10888/how-does-one-find-which-tags-they-created)
- and many other posts shown there among linked questions.

If I do not miss something when reading those questions (going through all of the linked questions seems to be virtually impossible because of the sheer amount of them), I see basically the following possibilities:

- Find the oldest question in the given tag. (Which does not always yield a correct result. The tag might have been added to an older questions which was deleted or retagged. Or the tag might have been actually created in a newer question and only later added to the older one.)
- Check whether [Taxonomist badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist) was awarded for this tag. (This only works if the tag has at least 50 questions. And IIRC this tag can only be awarded once, so it won't work if the tag creator already had this badge for another tag.)
- One more thing I try in such situations is checking the revision history of tag-wiki and tag-excerpt. At least on some occasions the user, who creates the tag, also creates the tag-wiki.

<sup>1</sup> Database schema is shown on the right when you click on [compose query](https://data.stackexchange.com/opendata/query/new). <s>I do not know a better link to it.</s> It is also shown here: [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) with more detailed explanations of some fields.

Comment: You could also ask for the identity of creating user to be recorded, while you are at it...

Comment: I've suggested in the post: *Or maybe even id of the user who created the tag or id of the question where it was created.*

Comment: [Jeff Atwood's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82/can-i-find-out-which-tags-i-have-created/6822#6822) 
to a related feature request (to show me the list of tags created by me, this is [tag:status-declined])
says that this would probably cause that some users would be gaming the system to get taxonomist badge.