# List of recently created tags

Tags: support, tags

What does the word recently in the tab with [recently created tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new) exactly mean? (The name of the tab is *new*, when I look at the tooltip, it only says *"recently created tags"*).

It there a way to list all tags ordered by the date of creation? (For example, if I would be interested in that tags that were created most recently, but from a longer period than shown in this tab). If I am not mistaken, creation date is [not stored in SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244396/what-about-adding-creationdate-to-tags-in-sede-database).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Judging by the *new* tabs on several Stack Exchange sites, *recently* here means *created in the past 45 days*; all sites I sampled have tags created on or after January 16th.

There currently is no way to list tags by their 'creation date'; even the [`/tags` API endpoint](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags) only lets you sort by popularity, name or date of last activity (which is the date of the most recently active question with that tag).